# GoogleSignInClient always return null on physical devices

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I found a lot of similar questions, but I have already implemented everything and it is not working. On virtual devices with Android 9, 10 and 11 it is working as expected, but not on physical devices using Android 9 and 11 (probably on all other physical devices as well).

Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    /*** process firebase auth with data...*/
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Weird error....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            //User logged to google
            /*** processing firebase auth etc... ***/
        } else {
            //User not logged to google
            Intent intent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
        }

    }
....
}
```

And here is buid.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
android {
    compileSdk 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxxx"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 2014
        versionName "0.2.14"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("${System.getenv("AC_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH")}")
            storePassword "${System.getenv("AC_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")}"
            keyAlias "${System.getenv("AC_ANDROID_ALIAS")}"
            keyPassword "${System.getenv("AC_ANDROID_ALIAS_PASSWORD")}"
            v2SigningEnabled true
            v1SigningEnabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.2'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'

}
```

After choosing Google Account, on virtual devices I'm logged in and successfully connected to firebase, but on physical devices I receive toast message because `result.getResultCode()` is not `Activity.RESULT_OK` and there is no other result data.

google-services.json is configured, as well as everything else regarding to firebase. Any idea how to solve the problem?

**UPDATE:**

Application is working regularly when run from android studio, on physical device or on virtual device.

When application is installed on both, physical or virtual device, as release or debug version, not working. Really weird.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have installed release app on virtual device. Of course not working as expected.

Then I run app from android studio on very same virtual device, I got warning that there is a same app with a different signature (???) and I run it. It works.

I quit the app, and run it from virtual device, now it is working.

Weird².

I stop the app, from android

Comment: Does device has [Google Play Services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms) installed?

Comment: Of course they do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

problem was in SHA-1 hash for the app. In `gradle.build` there was defined "default system keystore" (c:\users\(username)\.android\debug.keystore) for release. And app was signed with release keystore I have created. SHA-1 was build with file from `gradle.build`, so there was a mismatch. After making corrections in gradle.build, and created a new release SHA-1, I just add a new SHA-1 to firebase app, and all works just fine :)

part of `build.gradle`:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("C:\\projects\\android\\_keystore\\imath\\release.jks")
        storePassword "xxxxxxx"
        keyAlias "key0"
        keyPassword "xxxxxxx"
        v2SigningEnabled true
        v1SigningEnabled true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

So, with
`gradlew signingReport`
create both SHA-1, for debug and for release, and place them both in applicaton confuguration in Firebase.

```
> Task :app:signingReport
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Vojin\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: 1D:64:F8:1A:3E:33:26:CF:57:3F:3A:34:BE:84:F3:5E
SHA1: AD:9F:FD:C6:E9:64:75:18:B2:2E:E3:90:16:13:88:E8:55:AA:44:AD
SHA-256: 19:4E:D1:19:51:37:1D:8D:3C:32:B3:A1:C3:2F:3A:84:BA:C5:58:EC:13:E1:9F:B4:1F:73:B5:27:85:E7:1D:9E
Valid until: Wednesday, June 2, 2049
----------
Variant: release
Config: release
Store: C:\projects\android\_keystore\imath\release.jks
Alias: key0
MD5: 50:9F:1F:E7:1F:DB:39:40:33:55:71:40:6C:CF:86:EE
SHA1: C6:08:E0:87:A2:AB:2A:2C:AF:0D:22:03:86:F0:F8:48:C2:C8:59:20
SHA-256: B1:E8:35:AF:EB:49:79:A7:51:57:97:74:BA:0A:CD:2D:28:9D:45:FB:CD:06:50:26:44:BE:46:95:A6:F0:5F:FF
Valid until: Sunday, July 29, 2046
----------
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Vojin\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: 1D:64:F8:1A:3E:33:26:CF:57:3F:3A:34:BE:84:F3:5E
SHA1: AD:9F:FD:C6:E9:64:75:18:B2:2E:E3:90:16:13:88:E8:55:AA:44:AD
SHA-256: 19:4E:D1:19:51:37:1D:8D:3C:32:B3:A1:C3:2F:3A:84:BA:C5:58:EC:13:E1:9F:B4:1F:73:B5:27:85:E7:1D:9E
Valid until: Wednesday, June 2, 2049
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to add your sha1 to your firebase project  as follows :

Settings Icon -> Project Settings -> General Settings -> scroll down and paste your sha1 key

Comment: Try to put your code in try catch block and print the exception message , see what it says there

Comment: I have tried to run application on mobile device from android studio, and it is working. Just regularly installed app is not working

Comment: Do you have proguard enabled ?

Comment: Yes... I have changed to:
````       
release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
````
but still not working

Comment: since it is working when launched from android studio , then there is something in the configuration somewhere , because it if was an error , it would  not work on all devices but some misconfigurations may lead to partial errors